# Import/include external VirtualHost file to be used inside Apache's httpd.conf

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Would you know how to import a VirtualHost file into httpd.conf? For example:

```
start of httpd.conf:
    .
    .
    .
    Import team-virtual-host.conf
    .
    .
    .
end of httpd.conf

start of team-virtual-host.conf:
<VirtualHost 216.154.214.172:80>
    ServerName  bestrds.com
    blah blah blah
</Virtualhost>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simple:

```
include team-virtual-host.conf
```